# Difference between Net metering, Feed-in tariff and power purchase agreement

Tags: solar-energy

I have been reading on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feed-in_tariff#Compensation) about the 3 different kinds of compensations, when it comes to renewable energy, however, the 3 types of compensation seem identical to me. If I have produced excess energy, I would feed it in the power grid and get compensated for this. So what is the difference between the 3 methods (if there is any at all)?

Comment: I think this might be a good fit on sustainability.se. I've [asked about it on meta](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/q/308/3379) over there.

Answer (score 3):

Net metering gives you one meter. When generating more than you consume, the meter runs backwards.

Feed-in tariffs are different; I have this in the UK, and I have *two* meters. I'm paid a certain amount for electricity I generate. I can *also* use this for free. If I generate less than I use, the original meter runs forwards and I am billed in the normal manner. If I generate more than I use, it does not move. The FIT meter pays one amount and the normal meter charges another; they can be through two different companies.

Answer (score 1):

You can read from the article that the difference is in the *amount* you get paid for each unit of power produced:

- Feed-in - you get above-retail price, i.e. your power production is subsidized
- Net metering - you effectively get *exactly* the retail price; this may be the result of summing two compensating effects: Your power production may reduce the load across the grid, because electricity is produced in relatively small quantities (nowhere near the giga-Watts of a full powerplant) and tends to be used close to the production site, yielding savings for the grid operator; on the other hand, your power production may be unpredictable/uncontrollable which puts a burden on the grid operator who has to balance production and consumption at any time.
- Power-purchase agreement - you get less than the retail price, i.e. you're like a power plant company selling its electricity to retailers. This may make sense for large power plants which can produce great amounts of power at a constant level relatively cheaply, but are not so well-suited to quickly adjusting output to varying demands, which again may cost the grid operator trying to balance. This probably implies certain guaranteed purchase quantities as part of the agreement which gives the producer more security by shifting the risk of varying demand to the purchaser, and this risk needs to be priced in.